# How can run. Rails web app in AWS Lambda server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

AWS (Amazon web service) introduced serverless computing commonly known as AWS Lamda, We can store the asset in S3 then deploy a lambda function to handle our business logic. Lamda will support ruby script.

Is there any way to run a dynamic web framework like rails or Sinatra in Lambda server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem here is that AWS Lambda does not currently support Ruby.

> [AWS Lambda supports code written in Node.js (JavaScript), Python, Java
>   (Java 8 compatible), and C# (.NET Core) and Go](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

However if you really want to run a rack (including Sinatra and Rails) based app it is possible, by bundling your own version of ruby in your deployment package. [This blog post](https://www.sheakelly.com/blog/serverless-sinatra/) goes into detail about how to do that.

Whether this is a good idea probably depends on what you are trying to achieve.

**Update (3rd December 2018):** AWS Lambda now runs Ruby as an officially supported language: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-ruby-support-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: Blog post https://www.sheakelly.com/blog/serverless-sinatra/ is dead, if you can add a replacement, that would be great!